# Break output of command at full page or per line

Tags: command-line

I am trying to check if a package is already present in the my Ubuntu distro by using the command

`apt-cache search <name>`

the resultant output of command for Java package was very long and ran into several pages.

**My Question**

How to break the output in Ubuntu at a page full and every line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
    apt-cache search java | less
```

Use the arrow keys to scroll forward and backwards. Get out of less with q.

Comment: Arrow is causing one line at a time, can we scroll down one page at a time.

Comment: Sure, please try: PgDn.